# How can I display a long message text in the notification on API 7

Tags: android, notifications

I'm developing an Android app in which I have want to display a long piece of text in the notification bar.

My problem is my app in minimum API level 7. It is mandatory for client.

How can I display a long text in the notification bar? I saw documentation but big text API is  available in jellybean version.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, there is no way to change the size of notifications (to accommodate more text) prior to Jelly Bean. In the standard template (be sure to use the [NotificationCompat.Builder](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat.Builder.html) in the support-v4 library), you have two lines to work with: `contentTitle` and `contentText`.

If that's insufficient, you could go the route of specifying a custom view, into which you could try to cram more text at a smaller size (since the overall size of the view cannot change prior to JB). This will impact legibility, though, so be careful.

I think the best course of action, though, is to move the text somewhere else. Clicking the notification could produce a dialog box that includes the full text; hopefully your client will tolerate such a solution.